# VHDL strange behaviour

Tags: vhdl

I have this lines of code:

```
entity test is
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
              c : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0));
end test;

architecture Behavioral of test is

component adder is
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           s : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end component;

signal prod: std_logic_vector (15 downto 0) :=X"0000";
signal tempsum1,tempsum2: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0):=X"00";
signal cin,cout:std_logic:='0';

begin

--Working(modelsim can see the upper value of c)

S1: adder port map(tempsum1, prod(15 downto 8), c(15 downto 8));


--Not working(c gets a red line on all bits):
--I replace the first S1 with this one and assign later.
S1: adder port map(tempsum1, prod(15 downto 8), tempsum2);
c(15 downto 8)<=tempsum2;

end Behavioral;
```

Can somebody tell me why with the first block of code the c is set and seen in modelsim correctly and with the seccond is not?
Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't actually have the `-- Working` and `-- Not working` sections at the same time, right?

Comment: yes, different instances

Comment: The component instantiation label implicit declaration S1 is used twice in your sample code.  It shouldn't analyze successfully.  Besides that you have two drivers for c(15 downto 8), the first S1 adder (formal s)  and the concurrent signal assignment statement following the second S1 adder. The value of c(15 downto 8) will be determined by the resolution of the two drivers.

Comment: Ok, it seems that i confused you. It's different code, the first S1 is working but when i replace it with the seccond code is not.

Comment: What happens with the "Not working" code? I don't have modelsim immediately available to try to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to suppress the initialization in your signal declaration of tempsum2.